# Suppose $R$ is a ring with unity and $I \neq R $ is an ideal of $R$. Show that $R/I$ is a ring with unity with $1 + I$ as the unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Suppose $R$ is a ring with unity and $I \neq R $ is an ideal of $R$. Show that $R/I$ is a ring with unity with $1 + I$ as the unity.

---

Proof: (I think I need to make a assumption that $1$ whether in $I$)

Since $I\neq R$, then the unity of $R$ is not an element of $I$; If $1\in I$, then for all $r\in R$, $1\cdot r=r\in I$. Then $1+I\in R/I$. Thus $(1+I)(r+I)=r+I=(r+I)(1+I)\in R/I$. Therefore,  $R/I$ is a ring with unity with $1 + I$ as the unity.

---

Does the argument above valid? If not, can anyone show me where I did wrong or give me suggestion to write a better argument? thanks

Comment: $1\in I$ is almost never true—that would imply that, for any $r\in R$, we have $r\cdot 1 \in I$, so $I=R$.  Instead, you should argue that $1+I \in R/I$ directly from the definition of $R/I$!  You should also prove that $(1+I)(r+I)=r+I$, rather than merely stating it—this is the heart of the matter.

Comment: Also, if you are not assuming that $R$ is commutative, you should also check that $(r+I)(1+I) = r+I$, otherwise you have only shown that $1+I$ is a left-identity, rather than a two-sided identity.

Answer (score 2):

The argument is true. But note that even if $1\in I$, (i.e without assumption $I \neq R$),  then $(1+I)$ is the unity of $R/I$. In this case, $R/I$ is the *zero* ring $R/R$, and in *zero* ring $0_{R/I}=1_{R/I}$

---

Update.
$(1+I)(r+I)=(1*r)+I=r+I$

Answer (score 0):

$R/I =\{r+I: r \in R\}$

$(1)\ \ (r+I)+(s+I) = (r+s)+I$

$(2)\ \ (r+I)(s+I) = (rs)+I$

$(3)\ \ (R,+)$ is additive abelian group which means $(r+s)+I = (s+r)+I$

$(4)$ Multiplication is commutative in $R \Rightarrow (rs)+I = (sr)+I$

$(5)\ \  (r+I)(1_R+I)= (r \cdot 1_R)+I = r+I$